# Scheme: Combining lists at a certain point

Tags: list, scheme

I am trying to define a procedure that takes an argument of 2 lists and a non-negative integer. Assume perfect input.  I want it to construct a list of the elements in the first list UNTIL it reaches the given integer of elements at which point I want to finish it with the remainder of elements from the second list. Let me demonstrate.

```
~(combine '(a b c d e) '(w x y z) 2)
(a b y z)
```

Notice that the second list continued from the next index as if it were being made to cdr the whole time.

This is what I have. It doesn't work, of course and I think I may be using the wrong logic.

```
(define (combine seq1 seq2 point)
 (if (null? (or seq1 seq2))
   '()
   (if (equal? point 0)
       (cons seq2 '())
       (cons (car seq1) (combine (cdr seq1) (cdr seq2) (- point 1) )))))
```

All help would be appreciated!

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, this line doesn't do what you want:

```
(if (null? (or seq1 seq2))
```

In Scheme, the empty list is a **true** value; the *only* false value in Scheme is **#f**.  That means that

```
(or '() '(a))
```

returns **'()** but

```
(or '(a) '())
```

returns **'(a)**

So your check for null will return #t only half of the time.  (And if *'()* were a false value, as it is in regular Lisp, then it would *never* work, so I'm not sure what you are thinking).

If you want that line to return true if either of the lists is null, you will have to rethink it.

Then there's the line

```
(cons seq2 '())
```

Try testing that function on its own and see what happens - it's not what you need.  If you think about it, that line should be rather simpler.  What do you actually need to return at that point?

Comment: Okay I got it to do mostly what I wanted! Now I'm getting a list resembling

    ((a b) y z)

How can I combine the two lists? I would just use append but my teacher won't allow me.

Comment: Hmm.  It looks as if you're nearly there, but you maybe messed something else up a little.  I'm surprised because the very last line was entirely right. If you left the last line as it is, I don't see how you get your new result unless you're messing with seq1 elsewhere.

Comment: Actually it did turn out I had seq1 misplaced somewhere. I have fixed it and now the code is working perfectly. Thanks a ton!